# Verify that a column name is a unique identifier

Tags: python, pandas, data-mining

I have a dataset called df_authors and in that dataset I have a column called author. I have to verify that df_authors.author is a unique identifier.

What I tried, `len(df_authors) == len(df_authors['author'].unique())`, and this returns True.

My question is have I done this right. I found this line of code online and not a 100% sure if it does what I think it does.

My understanding of a unique identifier is that, each row in that column has unique values and this line of code checking each row against the dataset to be unique or not.

If someone could tell me if I'm right or way of here, I'd greatly appreciated it. Thank you.

Comment: seems like a decent approach, you can also use `df_authors['author'].duplicated().any()` and get `False` if there is no duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of a unique identifier is correct, however this line of code works a bit differently:

`len(df_authors)` gives you the number of lines in the DataFrame. `len(df_authors['author'].unique())` gives you the number of unique values in the `author` column. If both lengths are same, that necessarily means that `author` is unique.

You can also leverage pandas more directly by using `set_index`:

```py
df_with_index = df_authors.set_index('author', verify_integrity=True)
```

If the index is not unique, that statement will fail (because of `verify_integrity`), plus you will be able to use the author as an index, e.g.:

```py
df_with_index.loc[author]
```

Comment: Cool thanks for clearing up what I did. So 'df_with_index = df_authors.set_index('author', verify_integrity=True)' will return false or an error if not unique and return nothing but move to the next line if it is unique. Is that correct.

Comment: Yeah exactly -- it will raise an exception and stop executing (unless you catch the error), but it will keep running if the data is ok

Comment: Perfect, Thank you. Still trying to get my head around Data Mining. Thank you for your answer.